# Multiselect field not loading values correctly - Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am trying to load customer attributes in multi-select field in admin configuration. 
I do get the attributes but only get the initials of each one of them and not the full text. This is my code,

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
  $result = array();   
  $addressAttributes = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_address_attribute_collection');    
  foreach ($addressAttributes as $addressAttribute)   
  {        
      if (($addressLabel = $addressAttribute->getFrontendLabel()))  
      $result[$addressAttribute->getId()] = $addressLabel;   
  }
 return $result;
}
```

And this is my system.xml code

```
<fields>
    <attributes>
        <label>Attributes</label>
        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
        <source_model>customerattributes/attributes</source_model>
        <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
    </attributes>
</fields>
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source models are generally useful when toOptionArray() returns an array of the following format:

```
array (
        array("label" => "First label to Display", "value" => "value1"),
        array("label" => "Second label to Display", "value" => "value2"),
);
```

The above would be rendered as follows:

```
<select ... >
    <option value="value1">First label to Display</option>
    <option value="value2">Second label to Display</option>
</select>
```

Perhaps if you change your function to the following, you'll see what you want:

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $result = array();
    $addressAttributes = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_address_attribute_collection');
    foreach ($addressAttributes as $addressAttribute)
    {
      if (($addressLabel = $addressAttribute->getFrontendLabel()))
          $result[] = array('value'=>$result[$addressAttribute->getId()],'label'=>$addressLabel);
    }

    return $result;
}
```